# SQL - Check Availability

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm planning to develop a hotel management system where each hotel has/have rate(s) for a particular set of days. Rate values are stored in another table which is fine.

Table is as below.

[image]

SQL query I use to check whether there are existing rates for a particular date range.

```
SELECT * FROM `hotel_rate` 
WHERE 
(from_date <= '2013-04-18' AND to_date <= '2013-04-22') OR
(from_date >= '2013-04-18' AND to_date >= '2013-04-22') OR
(from_date >= '2013-04-18' AND to_date <= '2013-04-22') OR
(from_date <= '2013-04-18' AND to_date >= '2013-04-22')
```

What I'm trying to do is add rate for the date range from '2013-04-18' to '2013-04-22'. There are already added rates for the date range from '2013-04-20' to '2013-04-23'. So I want to inform the administrator who's adding the rates that rates has been already applied for the particular period he/she has selected.

The problem is my SQL query fetch all the rows from the database where as I only want to get the particular row(s) where rates are overlapped. In my example result set should only contain row which has the id = 4.

Given that according to my knowledge before adding a rate I should check below 4 conditions. Two black lines show the existing rates for a hotel. Yellow lines show the possible overlapping scenarios. In a any given set 1st yellow line is from_date 2nd yellow line is the to_date.

[image]
How can I fix this ? How can I only get the overlapped rate row ?

Comment: +1 for the chuckle that picture gave me.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but in all cases, 1. the first yellow bar is before the second black bar and 2. the second yellow bar is after the first black bar. Until Einstein is proven wrong, that's all you need to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I am following, but it seems you want to determine if there are any records that have some kind of overlap with the two dates that are input.  If that is the case I would suggest this

```
SELECT * FROM `hotel_rate`
WHERE
  from_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
  OR to_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Here of course, the `?` are your two dates.  All that needs to happen to have an overlap is for either the from_date for a record or the to_date for a record to fall between the input dates (input dates inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

```
WHERE (from_date <= '2013-04-18' AND to_date >= '2013-04-18') OR
 (from_date <= '2013-04-22' AND to_date >= '2013-04-22') OR
 (from_date >= '2013-04-18' AND to_date <= '2013-04-22')
```

The first two check for any range that surrounds the from or to date.  The last check is for any range that is within the 2.

Comment: Mike Brant beat me to it, and his is certainly simpler.  Nice!